# Is there a line length limit of language recogniton in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

It seems after passing column 74, Notepad++ recognizes my Fortran90 code as a comment. Characters turn into light green and are not recognized by language interpreter. Is there a way to turn it off? I am using default settings.

Comment: Ok, found it. It seems default fortran recognizes the syntax according to F77 not F90 or F95. It is better to download Fortran FreeForm